# Tables using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm stuck on creating a table using CSS. The table needs to be 5 rows by 5 columns [TABLE NEEDED TO CREATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOo8.png)

these are the tips:

```
Table width is 500 pixels with a 4 pixel border - centered
"Horizontal and Vertical Alignment" is the table caption
5 rows x 5 columns
Each cell has a border of 2 pixels
The first row is a heading for all the columns "Cell Alignment With CSS" - you will need to use colspan
The second row has 5 headings - the first one spans over 4 rows
The height for the cells under (Row, Cell - 1, Cell - 2 and Cell - 3) headings is 60 pixels
Rows (3, 4 and 5) cells show the different text aligned within the cells
```

any help in the right direction for a foundation of this would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Table structure you have given can be made more easily with a grid system. 
It will be responsive also and you can adjust the layout for different screen sizes.
Have a look at this : [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

If you strictly need table, then show me what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Who uses tables nowadays? Think this homework question from your teacher is kinda obsolete, and incomplete too. But anyway for a start...

```
<style>
table {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:center;border:4px solid #000;}
td {border:2px solid #ccc;height:60px;}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><h1>Cell Alignment With CSS</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4"><h2>Heading 1</h2></td>
<td><h2>Heading 2</h2></td>
<td><h2>Heading 3</h2></td>
<td><h2>Heading 4</h2></td>
<td><h2>Heading 5</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
<td><p>text</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```